# why we use write buffer in mips?[cache]

Tags: caching, buffer, mips, cpu-architecture

On Computer Architecture lecture, I learned that the function of write buffer; hold data waiting to be written memory. My professor just told that it improves time performance.

However, I'm really curious *'how it improves time-performance'*?
Could you explain more precisely how write buffer works?

Comment: Writing data to a CPU cache is *fast*, writing to memory is slower, and writing to disk is *really slooow*.

Comment: Yeah, I know that concept, but 'write buffer' is  not only just waiting session but also will be written in  memory if there are any write miss. I think there is no difference without/ with buffer when it comes to time performance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The paper [Design Issues and Tradeoffs for Write Buffers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.44.7073&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes the purpose of write buffers as follows:

> In a system with a write-through first-level cache, a write buffer has
>   two essential functions: it absorbs processor writes (store
>   instructions) at a rate faster than the next-level cache could,
>   thereby preventing processor stalls; and it aggregates writes to the
>   same cache block, thereby reducing traffic to the next-level cache.

To put this another way, the two primary benefits are:

1. If the processor has a burst of writes that occur faster than the cache can respond, then the write buffer can store multiple outstanding writes that are waiting to go to the cache.  This improves performance because some of the other instructions won't be writes and thus they can continue executing instead of being stalled.
2. If there are multiple writes to different words in the write buffer than go to the same cache line, then these writes can be grouped together into a single write to the cache line.  This improves performance because it reduces the total number of writes that need to go to the cache (since the cache line contains multiple words).

Comment: An interesting potential use for a write buffer is to support a limited form of transactional memory; if the transaction fails, the write buffer (containing only transactional entries) can simply be invalidated. (For out-of-order processors, the store queue could provide a similar functionality.) If the interface to the next level of the memory hierarchy is shared between reads and writes, a write buffer can also allow reads (which can stall even an out-of-order processor) to be performed before earlier writes.

Comment: I completely understand what I've confused. thank you

Comment: @고지웅 if you find an answer to your question on stackoverflow helpful you may want to indicate this by clicking the checkmark on the answer to accept it.  See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more details about how this works.

Comment: @GabrielSouthern  Doesn't this assume that (1) there is a significant amounts of write
locality, for otherwise the probability of being able to batch
multiple writes in a cache line would be small; and (2) that the
probability is high that there is no data dependence between the
writes, suspended and other instructions?